# Where to keep sql statements?

Tags: android

I don't really like how the SQL statements look in the code, they make it less readable, even very very simple things look ugly. Is there any known 'best practice' I don't know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most things, it really depends.  Some options are:

- Stored procedures
- Repository pattern (encapsulate your SQL so that only in the core of your repository provider do you have SQL statements)
- Use an ORM, and let the ORM gen your SQL
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

I´m using properties files in XML format. That allows multi line values.